# $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [1,2,3, ..., n] $

Tags: functions

Is there a function that is of the form $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [1,2,3, ..., n] $ with $ n \in \mathbb{N} $?

I am looking for a way to assign a natural number to a natural number, but this second it falls in an interval $ [1, n] $
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'but this second it falls in an interval...'.

Comment: I think he wants the range to be limited to a certain subset of the natural numbers. In which case for me modulo immediately comes to mind.

Comment: For example, for $ n = 100 $, that the codomain of $ f $ be the natural ones in [1,100]

Comment: Doesn't $f(k)=1$ for all $k$ give an example of such a  function? May I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I think he wants $[1,n]$ to be the range, not just the codomain. So make it surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n = 1$, this is trivial: $f(x) = 1$.

If $n > 1$, then I suggest we use the modulo function, let's call it $mod(x,n)$ where $x$ and $n$ are integers. Essentially, the modulo function gives us the remainder if we were to divide $x$ by $n$. More formally speaking, $mod(x,n)$ is the smallest nonnegative value $k$ such that we can write $x = mn + k$ for some integer $m$. For example, $mod(67,10) = 7$ because $67 = 6\cdot10+7$, and this is the smallest such value for which we can write an expression of this form.

The codomain for this function is natural numbers in the interval $[0, n-1]$: by definition the value must be nonnegative, so the minimum is zero, and any value greater than or equal to $n$ cannot be correct because we could subtract $n$ to get a smaller viable nonnegative solution:

$$k\geq n, x = mn+k\to k-n \geq 0, x = (m+1)n + (k-n)$$

It is also clear that this function can only output integers because for $mod(x,n) = k$ we have that there is some integer $m$ such that $k = x - mn$, and because for our discussion $x$ and $n$ are also always integers, $k$ is an integer by the closure properties of integers on addition and multiplication.

Finally, the surjectivity of $mod$ is trivial because for any $0 \geq x \geq n-1$, $mod(x,n) = x$.

So for any natural $n > 1$, $f(x) = mod(x,n) + 1$ satisfies your desired properties.

Comment: I think it helps to take $ n \pmod{x} +1 $. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A function can be any mapping so just map them anyway you want.

For example I can assign $f(x) = 7$ always so that $f(x) \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ because $f(x) = 7$ always.

Or I can assign $f(1) =3$ and $f(2) = 5$ and $f(3) = 1$ and $f(4) = 3$ and $f(5)=5$ and $f(6) =1$ and just repeat over and over again.  Then $f(x) \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ because $f(x) = 1,3,$ or $5$ always.

Or you could use the remainder theorem.  For any integer $x$ there is a unique quotient and remainder so that $x = qn + r$ (and $0\le r < n$).  So jest let $f(x) = \begin{cases} r&\text{if }r\ne 0\\n&\text{if }r = 0\end{cases}$.

That way if $n=7$ we'd have $f(1)=1; f(2) =2.....,f(6) = 6; f(7) = 7; f(8) = 1; f(9)=2$.....etc.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, there are many such functions.

For example,

$$f(k) = min(k,n)$$

or

$$f(k) = modulo(k,n)$$

Comment: $\min$ is also a really smart answer, good job on that